# SQL join table with same column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join two tables with the same column names and update it using by ID (unique key)

[image: table structure]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: What does "expected" mean? Which one do you want updated?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name phpmyadmin localhost

Comment: @aleksv i want to update table 1 and (expected) is the output what im looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your Example:

```
select * from Table1;
+----+------+------+--------+
| ID | Name | age  | Gender |
+----+------+------+--------+
|  1 | Pars |   23 | M      |
|  2 | Pepe |   24 | M      |
|  3 | Pio  |   25 | M      |
|  4 | Pak  |   26 | F      |
+----+------+------+--------+

select * from Table2;
+------+------+------+--------+
| ID   | Name | age  | Gender |
+------+------+------+--------+
|    1 | Pars |   30 | M      |
|    2 | Pepe |   31 | M      |
|    3 | Pio  |   32 | M      |
+------+------+------+--------+
```

After the Update Query:

```
Update Table1 join Table2 using(ID) set Table1.AGE=Table2.AGE;
```

RESULT:

```
select * from Table1;
+----+------+------+--------+
| ID | Name | age  | Gender |
+----+------+------+--------+
|  1 | Pars |   30 | M      |
|  2 | Pepe |   31 | M      |
|  3 | Pio  |   32 | M      |
|  4 | Pak  |   26 | F      |
+----+------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this may help you.....

The query uses the inner join to join the table1 and table2

```
SELECT T1.name1,T2.name2
FROM `table1` T1 
INNER JOIN `table2` T2 ON t2.name1=t1.PrimaryKey;
```

Comment: do i need to create table with same column first?

Answer (score 0):

Used left join to join the tables.
Try this code:-

```
select a.id ,
       coalesce(a.name,b.name) as name
      ,coalesce(b.age,a.age)as age
      ,coalesce(a.gender,a.gender)as gender
from table1 as a
left join Table2 as b 
on a.id=b.id
```

Comment: what 'a' and 'b' stands for?

Comment: alias name for table

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

```
update Table1 set Table1.age=Table2.age from table1 inner join table2 on Table1.id=Table2.id
```